# telebot всплывающее сообщение при нажатие кнопки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать всплывающее сообщение при нажатии на кнопку, как на скриншоте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример:

```
import telebot # pip install pyTelegramBotApi

bot = telebot.TeleBot('<token>')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='CLick me', callback_data='add')
    markup.add(button)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Some text', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):
    if call.data == 'add':
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling()
```

[`callback_data`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) - данные которые отправятся в [`CallbackQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) при нажатии кнопки.

Из [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) `callback_data`:

> Optional. Data to be sent in a callback query to the bot when button
>   is pressed, 1-64 bytes

Подробнее о `telebot` [читайте тут](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#pytelegrambotapi).