# Python Telebot API. Инлайн кнопки ничего не выводят

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Бот отправляет картинку в чат с двумя инлайн кнопками лайк и дизлайк

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_rand_photo(message):
  if message.text =='фото':

    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    msg=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ну как тебе?", reply_markup=keyboard)

    like_button= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=emojize("Like :heart:", use_aliases=True), callback_data='like')
    keyboard.add(like_button)

    dislike_button =types.InlineKeyboardButton (text=emojize("Dislike :broken_heart:", use_aliases=True), callback_data='dislike')
    keyboard.add(dislike_button)

    all_photo_in_directory=os.listdir(PATH)
    random_photo=random.choice (all_photo_in_directory)
    img=open (PATH + '/' +random_photo, 'rb')
    bot.send_chat_action(message.from_user.id,'upload_photo')
    bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id,img, reply_markup=keyboard)
    img.close()
```

Дальше обрабатываю событие инлайн кнопки

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
if call.data == "like":
   bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,   message_id=call.message.message_id, text=" nfdsfasdsads")
```

Дает ошибку

```
  Response body:
 [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no    text in the message to edit"}']
```

Получается, что сообщение нет для изменения. Как тогда сделать, чтобы по клику на инлайк кнопки он реагировал?

Comment: Зависит от того что у вас в сообщении, если там медиа контент то нужно использовать: [editMessageCaption](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagecaption)

Comment: ну вообще, бот отправляет картинку, под ней 2 инлайн кнопки-лайк дизлайк. При нажатии на кнопку бот должен ответить что нибудь в духе-ты нажал на лайк. Должно вроде просто реализовываться, но я что то не понимаю, где ошибился

Comment: Используйте `answer_callback_query` чтобы оповестить юзера что лайк поставлен

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768875/236727

Comment: Отлично, помогло! Спасибо большое:)

Answer (score 1):

Использовал

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):
 if call.data == 'like':
     bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='Ты    поставил лайк!', show_alert=True)
```